# Crimp spade connectors in breaker box?

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

I am installing an **Eaton CHSPT2ULTRA surge protector** to my **Siemens QP breaker box**.

[image]

[image]

The surge protector has (4) 14-gauge stranded wires to connect.  I had no problems making a tight connection with the green wire to the grounding bar, and to the white I added some stranded 10-gauge wire with a wire nut to reach the neutral bar, which is secured tightly.

The problem is that the black and red wires connected to the 50 amp breaker don’t seem too secure. If I tug on the wires somewhat they don’t come out, but I think if I pulled harder I could pull them out of the breaker without too much effort.

[image]

Taking a close look at the 50 amp breaker, it’s (of course) made for a much larger (8-gauge) wire.  Even with the screw all the way tight, there is still space at the bottom of the screw.  So it seems to me that the 14-gauge stranded wire just isn’t big enough for the breaker screw to hold the wire tightly.

[image]

***What is the best way to fix this loose connection at the breaker?***

- **Can I use crimp-on spade terminals to the two breaker wires?**  Is it up to code to have this connector inside a breaker box?  Gardner Bender makes a 16-14 AWG 4-6 Stud Spade Terminal, Vinyl Blue (10-Pack) that is rated for 600-Volt maximum rating as building wiring and 1,000-Volt maximum rating for signs and fixtures, and has UL and CSA safety listings.

[image]

[image]

[image]

- **Is there a better way to do this?**

Thank you!

Comment: Isn't the problem that you shouldn't use a 50A DP breaker with those 14AWG leads? What size of breaker does the surge protector say you should use?

Comment: I stand corrected. From the product manual: *"Locate a dedicated unused, or install a new 2-pole circuit breaker
in an available space closest to the location where the CHSP is
to be installed. A dedicated 2-pole 15 ampere circuit breaker is
recommended for use with CHSP devices, but use a 2-pole 50
ampere circuit breaker to achieve the full published ratings of the
CHSPT2ULTRA device. (The connecting wires do not carry supply
current. Instead, they carry only short-duration currents that are
associated with a transient event.)"*

Comment: Completely unrelated - I don't understand how this surge protector can protect from surges if its off the side of the distribution board, rather than in-line with the incoming supply feed.   I've asked about this in [chat] because its not a real practical question.   Feel free to chime in over there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### You are correct in addressing this, but the ring terminal isn't the right tool for the job

You are indeed correct that 14AWG is well outside the listed/labeled range of the lugs on a 50A Siemens QP breaker -- they're rated for 8AWG through 4AWG wire only.  However, nobody's tested them with ring tongue terminals either, so your ring terminal solution is off base.  What I'd do instead is use a *short* length of 8AWG stranded THHN and an appropriate wirenut as a *transition pigtail* to adapt the 14AWG leads on the CHSPT2ULTRA to a wire size your breakers are rated to accept.  (If you insist on doing this using crimped connections, you can use a suitable closed-end crimp splice instead of the wirenut, as doing the transition with a butt/in-line splice requires a special reducing splice connector, the [Panduit ESV8-ESV14-Q](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/panduit-corp/ESV8-ESV14-Q/9491297), that isn't a hardware store item.)

Comment: Even though the reducing splice connector is a neater solution (but also costly & hard to get), I think I'll just do the wirenut to a short 8AWG wire into the two breaker screws as you suggested.  Simple, easy, and I can do it today.  THANK YOU!.

Answer (score -3):

The type of screw terminals you have never makes reliable connections to stranded wires, the strands tend to come out and squeeze out when thermal cycling. Even with solid wire it needs to be thick enough to fill the hole, or it can wiggle around and get out.

If you want to use stranded wire with screw terminals, get a hexagonal crimper for $20 on aliexpress:

[image]

Get your crimp ferrules:

[image]

Thread, insert, squeeze...

[image]

This does not solve your small wire in big hole problem though. For that I'd use a 8ga crimp ferrule since that's the size that goes with the hole, stuff it with enough stranded wire to fill it (including the wire from the surge protector) and crimp the whole thing.

Comment: "stuff it with enough stranded wire to fill it" needs code citation verifying legality.

Comment: DV since this violates the breaker's listing

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Yeah, what would happen to the very thin wire connected to the surge suppressor if there is a short in the device and it is connected to a 50A breaker?... I've looked into the manual, and the device comes out of the box with these wires sticking out. There's even an excuse "it's only for transient current"... hmmm

Comment: @FreeMan If there was an electrical code in the US, twisty wire nuts wouldn't be legal on stranded wire ;)

Comment: @bobflux -- the issue is that panelboard-type breakers aren't tested, listed, or labeled to be used with ferruled wires

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Here (France) the crimp ferrules are mandatory to connect stranded wire to anything with screw terminals. Makes sense, since if you don't use ferrules, the stranded wires eventually come out. Besides, stranded wire is barely even legal for permanent installation in an electrical panel anyway. But since screw terminals have been obsoleted by cage clamps, it's a bit of an academic matter.

Comment: When OP sticks the 8ga wire and the flimsy one in a wire nut, I wonder how long they will stay in...

Comment: @bobflux -- 8 to 14 in the appropriate nut shouldn't be an issue -- one could use the reducing crimp I linked if they were paranoid though

Comment: I'm assuming that your comment about the lack of electrical code in the US is in jest. It is, apparently, different than the French code, but the NEC is rather detailed. Since that appears to be legal in France, but the asker is in the US (based on American English labeling on the breakers), it would be worthwhile for your to label your suggestion as legal in France and that one should check local code to verify legality elsewhere.